# How to access headers in Angular?

Tags: angular

How can you access the request headers in Angular? I am trying to get the Authorization Bearer access token to pass on to an api call through Angular.

Comment: post your trying

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)** to pass the Authorization Bearer access token to pass along with each API or Conditions you can add as well in the interceptor.

**Command to generate the interceptor**

ng generate interceptor  [options]
or
ng g interceptor  [options]

**app.module.ts** Configuration

```
providers: [
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoaderInterceptor, multi: true }
]
```

https://angular.io/cli/generate#interceptor-command

Demo how Interceptor looks like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
  import { LocalStorageService } from '../../service/localStorage/local-storage.service';

import { api } from 'src/app/helpers/api';
import { encryptData } from 'src/app/helpers/helper';

@Injectable()
export class HeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
        
            const authorization = this.localStorageService.getItem('access_token')
                ? this.localStorageService.getItem('access_token')
                : '4763ae99-57d3-499f-b083-ec61ae6b510e';
            return next.handle(
                request.clone({
                    setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authorization}` },
                }),
            );
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please provide what you have already tried and a more detailed description of what you are trying to do. I can give you a general answer, but if you were more specific and provided some code, I could give you a more specific answer.

Using the `HttpClient` service:

To view the headers of a response add `observe: 'response'` to the request `options` parameter. The response will then be of type `HttpResponse` with `headers` as a property.

```js
  getSomething(url: string): Observable<HttpResponse<Object>> {
    return this.http.get(url, { observe: 'response' });
  }
```

To add headers to a request add `headers` to the `options` parameter of the request.

```js
  postSomething(
    url: string,
    data: any,
    headerValue: string
  ): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: { 'my-header': headerValue } });
  }
  }
```